# What to do when a user has posted the same answer two times

Tags: discussion, review-queues

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5547845/zeeshan) user has posted what that looks like the same answer to a multiple of questions. What is the best way to deal with the case?

Comment: If it's the exact same answer, an automatic flag is raised and a mod will handle it. I don't know if it does the same for very nearly identical answers, but you can flag for a mod and explain, linking to the offending answers. Now if the answers are similar but tailored to the questions... I would look at the questions, decide if they are duplicates, and flag the questions for closure if they are. I'm not sure if a flag would be appropriate on the answers at that point.

Comment: Useful to know, the questions seem to be the exact same so they are probably flagged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can legitimately use the exact same answer to multiple questions, there are two main possibilities:

- The answer is too broad to fit all of the questions it's applied to.  Consider downvoting the (probably) unhelpful answers.
- The questions are duplicates of each other and should be closed instead of answered with the same answer.  Close/flag them as such.

Either way, you should comment on one of their posts and **let them know what they are doing wrong**.  If you feel the situation will not be resolved after informing them, you can raise a custom flag for a moderator and explain the situation.

Comment: Raising a custom flag for a dupe answer is a bit extreme if you ask me. Mod attention is for serious business only.